# How to make checkbox react to adjacent checkbox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have 2 columns of checkboxes (from "Form Controls") in Excel (2010) that will indicate whether one of two tasks are completed. The 2nd task cannot be completed until the 1st one is done, but there could be instances where both tasks in a given row are completed in the same day. To avoid any extra clicks, I would like to make it so that if the 2nd task is completed (and checked) then the first task becomes automatically checked.

How do I do this?

**For example:**

[image]

I want to be able to manually check cell `B5`, but if cell `C5` is checked, I want cell `B5` to be automatically checked.

- However, I don't want:

  - Unchecking `C5` to impact `B5`
  - Checking/unchecking `B5` to impact `C5`

---

I know I could "cell link" the second checkbox column to a 3rd column to create an output, but I don't know how to make the first column checkbox reactive to that...

- However, ideally, I'd like to forego additional columns if possible.

---

**FINAL Solution:**

I used @GaryStudent's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098086/4581200) to inform my final generalized solution:

1. Select all columns/rows of desired checkboxes
2. Run WhatIsName macro to change name of each check box to the underlying cell it's within:

   - Note: make sure checkbox is ENTIRELY within each given cell, or it won't work right!!

     ```
     Sub WhatsInaName()
       Dim bx As CheckBox
       For Each bx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
           bx.Name = bx.BottomRightCell.Address(0, 0)
       Next bx
     End Sub
     ```
3. Next, select last row of right checkbox column, right click, assign macro "CheckBoxSimplifier"

   ```
   Sub CheckBoxSimplifier()
   it. Applies to all rows above it for some reason
       Dim MySelf As CheckBox, OtherBox As CheckBox

       Set MySelf = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
       Col = Mid(Application.Caller, 1, 1)
       Col2 = Chr(Asc(Col) - 1)
       Set OtherBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Col2 & Mid(Application.Caller, 2))

       If MySelf.Value = 1 Then OtherBox.Value = 1
   End Sub
   ```

   - For some reason, the code only works if you apply the macro to the *final* row of check boxes.
   - Also, I found that I could onyl run the WhatsInaaName macro *once* per file. If I tried running it a 2nd time (e.g., after adding more rows), it failed to work correctly (and simply copied the final row from the previous time it was run.

Comment: You need to attach a handler and handle the event when "saved" becomes checked, and write code to make that handler locate the corresponding checkbox, and set its value.

Comment: If you un-check the **C5** checkbox, do you want the **B5** checkbox to also be un-checked ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No. I've now updated the question to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little trick relies on the *naming* of the CheckBoxes.

You can assign Names to all the checkboxes in the sheet.  Say we name them after their associated cells like:

```
Sub NameThem()
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1).Name = "C5"
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(2).Name = "B5"
End Sub
```

Then we assign a little handler to all the **C-type** checkboxes like:

```
Sub MACC5()
    Dim C5 As CheckBox, B5 As CheckBox
    Set C5 = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("C5")
    Set B5 = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("B5")
    If C5.Value = 1 Then B5.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Each handler sub would be customized to refer to the proper **B-type** box.

You can also make a general handler for all the **C-types**.

**EDIT1:**

Here is a general routine that you can use for all the **C**'s:

```
Sub GeneralHandler()
    Dim MySelf As CheckBox, OtherBox As CheckBox

    Set MySelf = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    Set OtherBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("B" & Mid(Application.Caller, 2))

    If MySelf.Value = 1 Then OtherBox.Value = 1
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

This short sub will rename all the checkboxes in the sheet to the address of their enclosing cell:

```
Sub WhatsInaName()
    Dim bx As CheckBox
    For Each bx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        bx.Name = bx.BottomRightCell.Address(0, 0)
    Next bx
End Sub
```

Just be sure the cell is big enough  to completely enclose the box.

Comment: How would I apply this to 500 rows of checkboxes? How do I make the names able to change so that the code works for each row?

Comment: @theforestecologist  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks, Gary. How would I assign names more generically? For example, instead of C5 and B5, how do I assign the column/row of the cell containing the checkbox?

Comment: @theforestecologist  If the boxes are completely within a cell, then I would loop over all the boxes and assign names to the based on the **box.BottomRightCell.Address**

Comment: How do I generalize your naming function? For example, instead of `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1).Name = "C5" `, how could I make C5 variable and based on whichever cell the check box itself is in?

Comment: @theforestecologist  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: I've tried your updates, but I can only get it to work properly for 1 row. After that, it does not work. Do You have an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Option 1:

Insert two activeX checkboxes to the two column you need them to be in. Checkbox in B5 will be CheckBox1 and C5 will be CheckBox2 then double click CheckBox2 in c5 and enter this code:

```
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
           CheckBox1.Value = True
        End If
    End If
```

Option 2:

create two form checkbox controls right click the checkbox in C5 and assign macro. Make sure you add this procedure into your sheet1 code on the editor and assign it to your checkbox:

```
Sub CheckColumnBCheckBox()
    Dim cb, cb2 As Shape

    Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")
    Set cb2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2")

    If cb2.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        If cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value <> 1 Then
            cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Option 3:

Use worksheet change event instead of checkbox. Have user enter "X" or "x" in the column B5 and C5 to mimic the same as checkbox: put this code in the sheet1 editor:
[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C500")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "X" Or Target.Value = "x" Then
            If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "X" Or Target.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "x" Then
                Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "X"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Although It prevents me from unchecking box 1 if both box 1 and 2 are checked, checking box 2 does *not* automatically check box 1.

Comment: are you sure you have the checkbox named correctly? Checking Checkbox2 will surely check CheckBox1

Comment: Yes. But interestingly when I open a new sheet and try it a 2nd time (without changing a thing), it works. I literally copied/pasted both times. Weird

Comment: Follow up question for you: how do I get activeX checkboxes to fit *within* a cell??

Comment: if can enable the develop tab and click "Design Mode" then select the checkbox and resize it's corners to fit your cell.

Comment: Tried that. But the text of the checkbox gets cut off. Can I change font size or text alignment *within* cell?

Comment: about copying it and now it works, you don't happen to have any other checkboxes on your sheet that might have the same CheckBox1 name associated with their controls do you?

Comment: Yup. I was just about to report that was the problem. :p. Your code works great - thanks! :. Now if I could just figure out how to format about 500 rows of these...

Comment: right click the checkbox and go to properties/font and change the size and alignment from the properties of the checkbox.

Comment: So, to have reactive checkboxes, do I *have* to use "activeX" checkboxes or is there a way to do this with "form controls" checkboxes, too? Just so I can understand their abilities...

Comment: you can use form control but you will have to write a procedure that will do what my code above does for each checkbox and assign it to the form checkbox.

Comment: Ok. Last question: how can I copy (possibly click and drag) this checkbox set-up for 500 additional rows??

Comment: put the checkbox in the correct cell and hold down the bottom right corner of the cell and drag down it will copy to the next cell and such. then just add the code above to each column C checkbox corresponding to it's B column counterpart checkbox.

Comment: back to the form control checkboxes. So you mean I would write a macro and apply it to each checkbox? If you could add that method/code to your answer, too, for thoroughness, that would make it ANSWER GOLD :D.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, it appears the macro doesn't copy properly to each additional row with the checkboxes. How do I get the macro to work for *each* row without having to edit the code/manually add it each time?

Comment: you will have to modify and create a new macro for each additional row of checkboxes unfortunately.

Comment: i think you are better off not using checkbox if you have that many checkboxes, i would just use the cell change event lets say, in place of the checkbox, you would just use cell B5 and either put a "X" in the cell and on cell change event change C5 vise versa.